# warning appears when using generic types and inheritance

Tags: java, generics

I created an abstract class of general type variables which other type (boolean, char, int) classes extend. I made a static method that creates these variables according to a given string, but I keep getting the warning *"reference to generic type should be parameterized"*. I know why this is happening, but I don't know how to solve this problem. Any help?

```
public static  Variable createVariable(String variableString) {
    switch (variableString) {
        case "int":
            return new IntVariable(variableName, variableValue);
        case "double":
            return new DoubleVariable(variableName, variableValue);
        case "char":
            return new CharVariable(variableName, variableValue);
        case "String":
            return new StringVariable(variableName, variableValue);
        case "boolean":
            return new BooleanVariable(variableName, variableValue);
        default:
            throw new VariableException();
    }
}

public abstract class Variable<T>{ ... }

public class StringVariable extends Variable<String>{ ... }

public class DoubleVariable extends Variable<Double>{ ... }

public class IntVariable extends Variable<Integer>{ ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you just need to change the return type of the method:

```
public static Variable<?> createVariable(String type)
```

That basically says, "I'm returning a variable of some type, but I have no information about what the type argument is."

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Jon Skeet's answer, you could rewrite your factory method like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings ( { "rawtypes", "unchecked" } )
public static <T>  Variable<T> createVariable(Class<T> varClass, String variableName, String variableValue) {
  if( varClass.isAssignableFrom( Integer.TYPE ))
    return (Variable)new IntVariable();
  else if ( varClass.isAssignableFrom( String.class ) )
   return (Variable)new StringVariable();
  ...
  else
    throw new VariableException();
}
```

This would not help you get rid of warnings (you'd have to suppress them), but would allow you to encapsulate the unsafe parts into the generation logic and use the generic type in the return value:

```
Variable<String> v = createVariable( String.class, "name", "value");
```

Note that the if-elseif-block is just an adoption of your switch statement. There might be cleaner ways to implement the actual factory logic, e.g. by using a `Map<Class<?>, VariableFactory>` where `VariableFactory` would be an interface/superclass for concrete factories like `StringVariableFactory` etc.